# V-FOR não está funcionando no meu APP?

Tags: vue.js, vue.js-2

Estou desenvolvendo um app em Vue.js porém estou com algum erro no array `data:` que contém algumas salas de bate-papo, se deixo apenas o template ele renderiza normalmente, porém ao inserir os dados com `data : function(){return {rooms : [{dados}]}}` o mesmo para de ser renderizado e nao me mostra erros.

> > Segue o código do arquivo `app.js`

```
const chatComponent = Vue.extend({
data: function () {
    return {
        user: {
            email: "adm@gmail.com",
            name: "Adm System"
        },
        chat: {
            messages: [
                {
                    email: "fulano@gmail.com",
                    text: "Olá eu sou o Fulano",
                    name: "Fulano",
                    photo: "https://placehold.it/50/000FFF/fff&text=00",
                    color: ""
                },
                {
                    email: "adm@gmail.com",
                    text: "Olá eu sou o Atendente",
                    name: "Adm System",
                    photo: "https://placehold.it/50/27ae60/fff&text=Eu",
                    color: ""
                },
                {
                    email: "adm@gmail.com",
                    text: "Não foi possível dar continuidade",
                    name: "Adm System",
                    photo: "https://placehold.it/50/27ae60/fff&text=Eu",
                    color: ""
                },
            ]
        }
    }
},
template: `
    <div class="card" style="width: 100%">
        <div class="card-header">Chat</div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <ul class="chat list-unstyled">
                <li class="clearfix" :class="{ left: !isUser(o.email), right: isUser(o.email) }"
                    v-for="o in chat.messages">
                            <span :class="{'float-left': !isUser(o.email), 'float-right': isUser(o.email)}">
                                <img :src="o.photo" alt="" class="rounded-circle"
                                     :class="{'rounded-circle-visit': !isUser(o.email), 'rounded-circle-user': isUser(o.email)}">
                            </span>
                    <div class="chat-body">
                        <strong><small>{{ o.name }}</small></strong>
                        <p class="text-primary">
                            {{ o.text }}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-md" placeholder="Digite a mensagem">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-success btn-md">Enviar</button>
                        </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>`,
methods: {
    isUser: function (email) {
        return this.user.email == email;
    }
}
});

const roomsComponent = Vue.extend({
data: function () {
return {
    rooms : [
        {id : "001", name : "PHP", description : "Entusiatas PHP"},
        {id : "002", name : "Java", description : "Entusiatas Java"},
        {id : "003", name : "C#", description : "Entusiatas C#"},
        {id : "004", name : "C++", description : "Entusiatas C++"},
        {id : "005", name : "Javascript", description : "Entusiatas Javascript"},
        {id : "006", name : "Vue.js", description : "Entusiastas Vue.js"}
    ]
};
},
template: `
<div class="col-md-4" v-for="o in rooms">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            {{ o.name }}
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            {{ o.description }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`
});
var componentTest = Vue.extend({
template : "<h1>Test</h1>"
});
var router = new VueRouter({
routes: [
{path: '/chat', component: chatComponent},
{path: '/room', component: roomsComponent}
]
});

new Vue({
el: '#app',
router: router,
template: '<router-view></router-view>'
});
```

> > Arquivo `index.html`

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Chat - Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div id="app">
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="app/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

> > Dependencias do `Vue`

```
"dependencies": {
"bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
"jquery": "^3.4.1",
"vue": "^2.6.10",
"vue-router": "^3.1.3"
}
```

Pode ser apenas algum erro simples na sintaxe, mas já faz tempo que estou tentando resolver que deve estar passando algum detalhe.

Comment: Testei aqui e funcionou perfeitamente, provavelmente ou você está usando algum plugin ou está usando a var em outro lugar... NOTE que você esqueceu do `<div class="row"></div>`, pode ser até algum CSS afetando o display por falta disto, mas no código em si está tudo OK (aparentemente). Um teste online: https://codepen.io/brcontainer/pen/xxbRqqo?&editable=true&editors=101

Comment: Guilherme postei o código completo, pois não sei se o outro componente está impactando no segundo, estou iniciando em Vue.

Comment: Isso tá errado `<div class="row">
    <div id="app">
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</div>` não é assim que se usa a classe row, os filhos de row são somente a classe col, tá todo errado teu HTML. Não to afirmando que é o problema, mas pode ser.

Comment: Realmente era isso mesmo, existe um mapeamento interno no vue para bootstrap?

Comment: Isso ai é como o bootstrap funciona, independente do VUE, col é sempre filho direto do row, não pode haver tags que não sejam do tipo col dentro de ROW, pq ai quebra o layout... Eu inclusive fiz um "framework" proprio semelhante ao bootstrap, mas com CSS e pseudo-element (`::after {}`) se a pessoa usar errado aparece uma mensagem de erro (sem precisar de javascript) acaso a pessoa erre, pq a maioria das pessoas nào entendem o básico desses kits/fws e só saem usando mesmo sem ler a doc, inclusive é raro ver quem use o sistema de colunas de forma adequada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problema solucionado inserindo uma `div` pai com a `class="row"` dentro do componente.

**No arquivo index.html**

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="app">
         <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</div>
```

**App.js**

```
<div class="row">
     ... dados do componente ...
</div>
```

Ou seja a árvore do bootstrap estava configurada de forma errada.